# Hibernate proxy returns sometimes null for an association

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eager-loading

I have the folowing (simplified) code:

```
@Entity
class AImpl implements A {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private BImpl b;
}
@Entity
class BImpl implements B {
    @OneToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private CImpl c;
}
@Entity
class CImpl implements C {}
```

Provided that there is a connection between A(id=1) and B(id=1) and between B(id=1) and C(id=1) this assertion fails in about 20% of the runs (em ist an instance of EntityManager, there is an ongoing transaction):

```
AImpl a = em.find(AImpl.class, 1l);
BImpl b = em.find(BImpl.class, 1l);
Assert.assertNotNull(b.getC());
```

Why? b is returned as a proxy, but I would expect that all eager associations are already loaded, but it is not always the case.
When I skip the first line (loading of the object a), the b is not a proxy, and assertion is always correct.

With debugger I have noticed that in 20% of cases I get directly into the BImpl entity's getter and in other cases JavassitLazyInitializer comes into play.

Comment: There is no way the code would fail in 20% of cases unless there is concurrency involved. Hibernate's behaviour is pretty deterministic and won't depend on probabilities. From the code above it's not clear what could be the issue - it doesn't have save/update logic as well as ID generation strategies. Also, I'd remove interfaces - they are not relevant here.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Thank you for your comment. Interestingly, if I access the propery getC() with a B reference (not BImpl), I do not have this problem.